# Strength of nucleophiles among SN1 and SN2 reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, carbocation

As per the theory of chemistry, we say that unstable carbocations undergo S<sub>N</sub>2 reactions as it involves strong nucleophile. As a consequence, it does not lead to the formation of reaction intermediate, i.e. a carbocation.

Similarly, in stable carbocations undergo S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction by substitution of a weak nucleophile.

Why necessarily weak nucleophiles are involved? In case of S<sub>N</sub>2, since the carbocation is unstable, a strong nucleophile which prevents the formation of carbocation. But in S<sub>N</sub>1, since stable carbocation is involved, why shouldn't both strong and weak nucleophiles be involved?

Comment: Don't use Capital letters in titles.

Comment: I find your question confusing. Could you clarify it?

Comment: *Why necessarily weak nucleophiles are involved* - not always: you can have an SN1 reaction with strong nucleophiles as well eg cyanide.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Doesn't cyanide in Sn1 conditions form isonitrile compound? Since it is ambient I mean.

Comment: @AdityaRoychowdhury you mean ambivalent? yes, it can form an isonitrile, but if a covalent cyanide eg silver cyanide is used. With KCN/NaCN it forms a nitrile.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be true only because [S<sub>N</sub>1 reactions prefer polar protic solvents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN1_reaction#Solvent_effects) which stabilize both the leaving group and the carbocation. But such solvents also [surround strong nucleophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvent_effects#Substitution_reactions) and hinder it from the carbocation.

Weak nucleophiles on the other hand don't interact with protic solvents as much and thus stand a better chance of getting close to carbocation.

Comment: This feels like a comment more than an answer.. Some references attached to it would make it better. Not downvoting since it seems to answer the question though..

Comment: @Safdar, not sure what to reference for generic chemistry question. I added links to wikipedia, hopefully this is enough.